# More than the maximum allowed number of headers in Netty

Tags: netty, gateway

Please advise how I can increase maximum allowed number of headers in Spring Cloud Gateway. The thing is that I have the following error message: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: More than the maximum allowed number of headers, [100], were detected".

I cannot find how to set in Netty Server which is used in Gateway.

Many thanks in advance.